# How do I access my usb keyboard firmware in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, driver

I bought a mechanical keyboard recently and im trying to access the firmware just to poke around and mess with it. However, Im unable to figure out how exactly go about this. I've looked at some other posts that tell me to access /lib/udev/rules.d but that didn't help. I'm trying to access the keyboard's firmware and see if I can change key-press values and mess with the LED on my keyboard. Some help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I think you meant driver. Your keyboard is able to handle usb commands and they should be detailed into a datasheet and a subset of those used in the keyboard host driver so ubuntu can receive input from the keyboard.

A good idea would be to look for example code from the manufacturer/hobbyists, but this does not need to be into the ubuntu driver: I had an Alienware computer with LEDs on the keyboard and Alienware supplied example C project to compile and use the driver to do whatever you want.